# What am i doing wrong? Stack with character graphic(C++)

Tags: c++, char, stack

This is showing some cartoons( XD :D) instead of int values. I just want blank spaces where stack is empty so i pass empty string.What i am doing wrong??? and, by the way, i show graphics with simple character, not with some graphic library.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void pushh(int);
void pop(int);

int val;
char stack[4];
char a[1]="";

int main()
{

    cout<<"                    Stack Graphic representation\n\n\n\n\n";
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            stack[i]=a[1];    
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"\t\t\t4   |"<<stack[3]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t3   |"<<stack[2]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t2   |"<<stack[2]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t1   |"<<stack[0]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t    |___|"<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    pushh(1);
    cout<<"\t\t\t4   |"<<stack[3]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t3   |"<<stack[2]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t2   |"<<stack[1]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t1   | "<<stack[0]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t    |___|"<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;

    pushh(2);
    cout<<"\t\t\t4   |"<<stack[3]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t3   |"<<stack[2]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t2   | "<<stack[1]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t1   | "<<stack[0]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t    |___|"<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    pushh(3);
    cout<<"\t\t\t4   |"<<stack[3]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t3   | "<<stack[2]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t2   | "<<stack[1]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t1   | "<<stack[0]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t    |___|"<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    pushh(4);
    cout<<"\t\t\t4   | "<<stack[3]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t3   | "<<stack[2]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t2   | "<<stack[1]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t1   | "<<stack[0]<<" |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t    |___|"<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
};
void pushh(int val)
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(stack[i]==a[1])
        {
            stack[i]=val;
            break;
        }
        //break;
    };
};
```

Comment: Not using a loop to output that stack, for one. Egads. That aside, what are you trying to accomplish with that `pushh()` function, because it certainly isn't "normal" You're using a null terminator of a global character array of length-1 as your "comparison" value? Huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw "black spaces" use space `" "` instead of empty string `""`.

--EDIT--
also at the top of your code you have,

```
cout<<"\t\t\t3   |"<<stack[2]<<" |"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t2   |"<<stack[2]<<" |"<<endl;
```

But i guess you wanted to show `stack[1]` below `stack[2]` like this,

```
cout<<"\t\t\t3   |"<<stack[2]<<" |"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t2   |"<<stack[1]<<" |"<<endl;
```

--EDIT--

In windows, display character table is different than the ascii table for characters from 0 to 31. for example if you print integer 0, you will get a beep from the mother board speaker. for 1 you get a smiling face. etc. check this [Table](http://www.google.lk/imgres?sa=X&biw=1366&bih=633&tbm=isch&tbnid=5U3vhLyq3QRqZM:&imgrefurl=http://www.goldparser.org/articles/character-sets.htm&docid=2DJhCAHXj182sM&imgurl=http://www.goldparser.org/images/chart-set-ibm-pc2.gif&w=304&h=280&ei=tR6HUoD8KKKziAef8oGIAw&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:53,s:0,i:251&iact=rc&page=4&tbnh=173&tbnw=188&start=53&ndsp=24&tx=45&ty=72) for more info.

You have to input `char values` to your program like `'2'` to print them properly.

Comment: I use " " instead of "" by declaring a[2].But same result.

Comment: change `push(2);` to `push('2');`

Comment: I only provided a quick hack for you. but, you have to learn why it is like this. Try reading about "ASCII representation" and "Casting char to int in C++" and "Casting int to char in C++". Just google them. Best of luck. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the argument of function pushh(), ascii code of 1 is SOH, which is a special character. 
your program is intended to do value insertion in all indexes of your stack array. 
go through : http://ascii.cl/ and check if your problem statement is matches to the solution.